# How to add flutter gradient

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFyFK.png)
How does flutter implement such a style of button

I tried using shadows, but shadows don't have transparency,gradient is an odd choice
Here is the code:

```dart
Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                          
                            Color(0xff00FF5B).withOpacity(0.7),
                            Color(0xff34CB82).withOpacity(0.0),
                          ],
                         
                          stops: [
                            0.0,
                            0.1,
                          ]),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '000',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using RadialGradient along with changes in opacity ( withOpacity()).

Another approach can be making use of Stack.
Try making a background and stacking it with opacity changes (but again you will have to use gradient) and then finally stack your Icons or fonts on the button.

Another idea is to again using stack.
Make a button(let's call it x) with the base color(here green for example) and stack it with container (let it be y) with that color you want in center of button (also you can give opacity) and then provide shadow to this new container y with same color as that of x(i.e. green shadows). I guess it should give the desired effect.